# Resistive heater causes voltage drop

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, power

I'm trying to build a heater circuit via a 1 Ohm flexible heater, si2312 N-Mosfet and msp430fr2033.

[image: Circuit]

My problem is whenever I activated the mosfet the voltage drops and that causes Brownout Reset. When I put a resistor in series to heater everything works fine but resistor dissipates a lot power.

How can I control the heater effectively and efficiently? This will be a battery powered unit.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your schematic. I, for one, don't understand it.

Comment: What kind of battery are you using? Show the rest of your circuit

Comment: Voltage is dropping when the current is too big for the power supply.

Comment: Are you connecting your heater to the mosfet gate?

Comment: @AhmedM.Zahran I *hope* the heater is denoted by the inductor symbol here....

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think the problem is more than a voltage drop

Comment: My guess as to what the schematic means is that the inductor symbol is the actual heater / (heater+resistor combo), and the Heater node is a logic input to turn it on or off.

Comment: So more info. About battery, heater volatge and current are needed to identify the main problem reason.

Comment: Sorry for the inductor symbol :)
I'm using a power supplier that can support 5A. I don't have exact specifications of the heater but I believe it's 12V 12W.

Comment: 1 Ohm and 12V 12W? Not working together. 12V 12W makes it 12 Ohm. First get your specs straight.

Comment: If it is really 1 Ohm, and you connect it to 12V... well, you can calculate the current. And it is way above 5A.

Answer (score 1):

If the heater is actually a 12W heater as shown in your comments then it should be 12 ohms, not 1 ohm. If it's 1 ohm it would draw 12A, which is 144W. It's also more than your 5A power supply can supply so there is your problem.

Also, your schematic shows the heater connected to the **source** of an N-channel MOSFET, which is clearly wrong (the heater would never turn off because the body diode would conduct, and the MOSFET would heat significantly).

It would be best to use a lower voltage power supply or a more appropriate heater. At 3.3V your existing heater would draw 3.3A and produce about 12W. Alternatively, you could use a 12 ohm heater drawing 1A and producing 12W.

It's possible to use PWM directly on the heater, as others have suggested, or you could produce a 3.3V 3A power supply with a buck regulator, which might produce less EMI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the resistance of the load on the battery or increase the battery output current (by paralleling batteries or by using a bigger battery). If its a 9V battery the *source resistance* of the battery will be too high (more than 1 ohm) and the battery will not be able to source enough current.

What can you do about it? Start by increasing the resistance of the heaters, if you have more than one heater, wire them up in series, start with 4 or 6 1ohm flexible heaters in series.

You might be able to pulse the 1 ohm heater for a very short time, and use a capacitor to get you through the brownout.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as laptop2d.  You could use a PWM output at low duty cycle from the MSP430 with a large enough cap on the supply to support the current pulses.  You could gradually increase the PWM until you find the point where you get in trouble, then back off to get some margin.  (Or you could properly characterize your supply and calculate what duty cycle you need.)

Comment: I have tried using PWM still same, interesting point is even if I just turn on for 1us the reset occurs as
turnOnHeater();
__delay_cycles(1);
turnOffHeater();
No loop or anything.

Comment: @comingToBesiktas - of course, even a short pulse is going to draw a huge current, so you either need a capacitor downstream of a diode to power the MCU, or you need to put some inductance in the system so that you can use PWM to limit the peak current as well - in the latter case, you're basically building a switching power supply to produce a lower voltage source to drive the heater.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the basic problem is that your heater takes more power to run than the battery can provide.  If so, then no amount of clever circuitry can fix that.  That's fundamental physics issue.

Either use a bigger battery or live with less heater power.

You can still use the existing heater at less power.  That's what the resistor in series did.  However, that's a horribly inefficient way to reduce heater power.  As you noticed, the series resistor dissipated a lot of power on its own, which is why it got hot.

You could try using PWM to control the power into the heater.  For example, on for 5 µs every 10 µs will result in half power, and half the average current drawn from the battery.  The instantaneous peak current will still be the same, but for short intervals that average over 10 µs, for example, the battery will "see" the average.  This would be helped by putting a capacitor across the battery.

This is all assuming that the FET is used correctly as a switch.  The schematic you show makes no sense with the heater connected to the FET gate.